# Why don't my files show up in Github after pushing from local?

Tags: git, github

This one should be my first push from the local repository I've created with git to my Github repository. I believe my issue comes from my attempt of pushing, maybe something I misunderstood. By the way, in what follows I show to you the git commands I've typed into my terminal with comments:

Once I'm in the folder with all and only the files I want to store into the master branch of the repository, I type

```
git init
```

and I've initialized my git repository.

```
git add .
```

I've added all the files in the folder into the master branch of the local repository previously created

```
git commit -m "That's the first commitment!"
```

Now that the commitment is ready, I create a repository in my GitHub account, the link of which is https://github.com/stefanovic80/physicsComplementsITISstudents

Here comes the issue:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/stefanovic80/physicsComplementsITISstudents
```

in order to provide a kind of link between the local repository and the one on GitHub. I expect that after typing

```
git push -u origin master
```

and providing my username and token, I will have a copy of all the local repository on my GitHub account. Git does not provide any message of error, but still, it looks like something I misunderstood here, as all I get in my GitHub account is reported in the following screenshot

[image]

I don't see any copy of the files in the folder previously mentioned. It looks like everything is ready, but still, I do not have any copy of it.

Is there anything else I should have to type into the terminal? Is there anything wrong I did?

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are pushing to the `master` branch, where github is defaulting the main development branch to `main`. your branches and your changes are there, just in a different branch.

[image]

You need to either:

- push to your `main` branch instead of `master`

  - initially: `git push -u origin main`
  - to change a wrong upstream (in your case): `git branch  -u origin/main`
- or change the default branch to `master` (not recommended)
  [image: change default branch]